# How to validate male/female through text box in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

How to validate male/female through text box in HTML?

**JavaScript:**

```js
function myFunction(evn) {
    var x = document.getElementById("gender");
    if(x.value != "MALE" || x.value != "FEMALE")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**HTML:**

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(event)" name="gender" maxlength="6" style="text-transform: uppercase" title="ENTER VALID MALE,FEMALE" autocomplete="off"/>
```

Comment: Why not use radio button for this?

Comment: Always gonna return false, since it will always be either != MALE or != FEMALE.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction(evn) { 

var x = document.getElementById("gender");
if(x.value.toUpperCase() != "MALE" && x.value.toUpperCase() != "FEMALE") {
    return false;
}

alert("Good text!");
return true;
}
```

Also in your input element, you need an `id="gender"` because .getElementById doesnt work with just name attribute

Comment: You should really explain how your answer resolves OPs question.

Answer (score -1):

`

> 

```js
function myFunction(evn) {
    var x = document.getElementById("gender");
    if(x.value != "MALE" || x.value != "FEMALE")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```css
function myFunction(evn) { var x = document.getElementById("gender"); if(x.value.toUpperCase() != "MALE" && x.value.toUpperCase() != "FEMALE") { return false; } alert("Good text!"); return true; }
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myFunction(event)" name="gender" maxlength="6" style="text-transform: uppercase" title="ENTER VALID MALE,FEMALE" autocomplete="off"/>
```

`

Comment: Can you explain in the answer how it fixes the original question. You have effectively copied the other answer from 2016 here too.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be putting JavaScript in the CSS portion of a snippet.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myFunction(evn) {
    var x = document.getElementById("gender");
    if(x.value != "MALE" || x.value != "FEMALE")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```css
function myFunction(evn) {
    var x = document.getElementById("gender");
    if(x.value != "MALE" || x.value != "FEMALE")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
function myFunction(evn) {
    var x = document.getElementById("gender");
    if(x.value != "MALE" || x.value != "FEMALE")
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Why have you used a snippet and put JavaScript in the HTML and CSS parts!. You should also really explain what you have done and how it answers the question.